# How to get class from widget area

Tags: widgets

So... I registered my widget areas with this code:

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Posts Widget Area', 'ikos' ),
    'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
    'class'         => 'post-w',        
    'description' => __( 'Shown only in Blog Posts, Archives, Categories, etc.', 'ikos' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Note that I added a class. I want to "grab" the class (dynamically) and use the same code for all sidebars...something like:

`<div id="sidebar" class="`**HERE THE CODE THAT GRABS THE CLASS**`" role="complementary">`

But I don't know how to code that tiny thing. Help please :)

**EDIT**
I am using this code to "wrap" my sidebars in functions.php

```
// Before Sidebar - do_action('st_before_sidebar')

// call up the action
if ( !function_exists( 'before_sidebar' ) ) {

function before_sidebar($columns) {
if (empty($columns)) {
// Set the default
$columns = 'five';
} else {
// Check the function for a returned variable
$columns = $columns;
}

// Apply the markup
echo '<div id="sidebar" class="'.$columns.' columns" role="complementary">';
}
} //endif
// create our hook
add_action( 'ikos_before_sidebar', 'before_sidebar');  



// After Sidebar
if ( !function_exists( 'after_sidebar' ) ) {
function after_sidebar() {
// Additional Content could be added here
   echo '</div><!-- #sidebar -->';
}
} //endif
add_action( 'ikos_after_sidebar', 'after_sidebar');
```

**EDIT 2**

In pages I just call the sidebars `get_sidebar('page');` and inside the sidebar-page.php I call the before and after action written in functions. I need to add a dynamic variable for the classes...is there a way to do so?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You've shown your code for registering the widget, can you show us what you are using to display the widget on your site?

Comment: I edited my question with the code that wraps and shows my widget areas

Comment: Where is the `ikos_before_sidebar` action from? Is it a parent theme or theme framework? Which parent theme is it?

Answer (score 1):

Sidebars are stored in a global variable named `$wp_registered_sidebars`.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'before_sidebar' ) ) {

    function before_sidebar( $columns = 'five' ) {
        global $wp_registered_sidebars;

        $class_name = $wp_registered_sidebars[$columns]['class'];

        // Apply the markup
        echo "<div id='sidebar' class='$class_name' role='complementary'>\n";
    }
}
```

I assumed that $columns contains the sidebar ID. The value passed into `before_sidebar()` is the name value given to '`id'` (`'id' => 'primary-widget-area'`) in the arguments. I say that because naming that variable `$columns` seems strange.

Comment: I added the code that I am using to wrap and show my widget areas. It is in functions.php, is the code in your answer dynamic? I mean..I need to grab the class of each sidebar but I have 6 sidebars. I'd like to use the same code and just grab a var of each... or something :/

Comment: You would call it like this: `wpse_113801_add_dyanmic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );`. If you want all 6 sidebars on a page just loop through the sidebar ids.

Comment: In pages I just call the sidebars `get_sidebar('page');` and inside the sidebar-page.php I call the before and after action written in functions. I need to add a dynamic variable for the classes...is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes, but that necessary information was not included in your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sorry I will edit my question...I am sorry I am lame expressing myself! heh

Comment: Hmm it "strips out" the class. The class is empty, and the debug is saying: Notice: Undefined index: in this line:`$class_name = $wp_registered_sidebars[$columns]['class'];`